# Crash program when no break point, but not when hit a break point

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, visual-studio-2015, chromium-embedded

I'm using ChromiumWebBrowser in my program. I created a UserControl to contain a ChromiumWebBrowser instance, and in the MainForm, I load UserControl into a SplitContainer.
When I debug my program, If I hit a breakpoint into dispose method, program run correctly.
[image]

But if I delete breakpoint, and run debug, then program crashed. 
[image]

I can not find the cause of the error. Anyone explain to me?

Comment: Maybe there's another thread running which is trying to access your controls? When you hit a breakpoint it has time to end and then you can proceed?

Comment: what exception is thrown?

Comment: This is race condision you are dealing with. Please, provide more information on other threads running in parallel.

Comment: I already try-catch everywhere, but were unable to catch any errors, so I don't know what exception :(.
I've tried sleep a few second before dispose control, but errors still occurred.

Comment: @Carl my program in single thread

Comment: "By default, the debugger can only diagnose exceptions that are raised on a thread started by managed code." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381842/vshost32-exe-stopped-working-but-i-can-continue-debugging

Comment: I'd almost suggest you remove controls from their parent before trying to `Dispose` them. Also if your using a `CEF` based framework (you really should tag which one), then it's multi threaded, so you must be careful which handlers you call what from.